# How to know the login user of a docker image?

Tags: docker

I'd like to know the default user of a docker image (e.g., `publicisworldwide/python-conda`) from command line. Is there a way to do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will refer : [python-conda:dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/publicisworldwide/python-conda/dockerfile) which shows default user is lion.

You can retrieve that default user value from $USER variable as well.

Without Dockerfile and starting container , below command can be used.

```
docker image inspect <image_name> | grep 'User'
```

Comment: I'd like to directly get from an image. As for this example, you can track down a docker file. But there be case only image is known, but not the docker file.

Comment: You can execute docker image inspect <image_name> | grep 'User' and look for User section that will have the default user in it.

Answer (score 0):

Every docker image can have multiple users and their definition of "default user" may differ.
Here comes to the rescue, environment variables defined in Dockerfile.

```
docker exec CONTAINER bash -c 'echo "$CONTAINER_USER"'
```

This will get the CONTAINER_USER variable(which is usually the default user) from the **running** container via bash shell.

More information regarding [docker/exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/#run-docker-exec-on-a-running-container).

Comment: But this requires the start of a container. How to get the default user without starting a container from the image?